# How do NGINX sites-available work with subdomains?

Tags: nginx

This is my first time using NGINX.

I created a subdomain at *blog.domain.com* and it's working fine. I now tried creating a subdomain *wp.domain.com*, but all it does it redirect to the *blog.domain.com*.

This is the *blog.domain.com*:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name blog.domain.com;
    root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root; # Used for acme.sh SSL verification (https://acme.sh)

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

And this is the *wp.domain.com*:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name wp.domain.com;

    root /var/www/wp.domain.com;
    index index.htm index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files and ensure that both `server` blocks are present. Also, one of your `server blocks listen on IPv6 and the other one does not.

Comment: @RichardSmith just tried that and *wp.domain.com* does not appear.

Comment: If your distribution uses `sites-enabled` (see the `include` statements in your `nginx.conf` file), you may need to add symbolic links from `sites-available`.

Comment: When I go to the IP address (only) I get the same content as on *blog.domain.com*. I now get the server when running `nginx -T`.